# Let $A$ be the diagonal operator on $\mathcal H$ given by $Ae_n=\lambda_n e_n$, where $\sup_n|\lambda_n|<\infty. $ what is $\{A\}'$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Definition**:  The **commutant** $\mathcal{S}'$ of a subset $\mathcal{S} \subset B(H)$ is $ \{A \in B(H) : AB=BA \ , \ \forall B \in \mathcal{S}  \} $.

Let $\mathcal H$ be separablr Hilbert space with $\{e_n\}$. Let $A$ be the diagonal operator on $\mathcal H$ given by $Ae_n=\lambda_n e_n$, where $\sup_n|\lambda_n|<\infty. $

> **determine:**

> $\{A\}'$ and $\{A\}''$

**My attempt:** It is possible that a diagonal matrix $B$ commutes with a matrix $A$ when $A$ is symmetric and $A B$ is also symmetric. We have

$$
BA = (A^{\top}B^\top)^{\top} = (AB)^\top = AB
$$

So that $\{A\}'$ = set of all  matrix $B$  such that $A B$ and $B$ are  symmetric

Am I on the right track with this?. Can anybody help?

Thanks so much for your time and your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really on the right track (besides the fact that Hilbert spaces are usually complex and infinite-dimensional, so you want to talk about adjoints and not transposes).

The thing to pay attention is repetitions in the list $\{\lambda_n\}$. You should first do the case $\dim H=2$ with $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the canonical basis, so $B(H)=M_2(\mathbb C)$. Then do $B(H)=M_3(\mathbb C)$.

After that it should be fairly easy to understand what happens in the general case, but writing it out explicitly is painful if the repetitions (or lack of them) in the list $\{\lambda_n\}$ are not specified.

Comment: $$AB = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1b_{11}  & \lambda_1b_{12}& \lambda_1b_{13}\\ 
\lambda_2b_{21} &\lambda_2b_{22} &\lambda_2b_{23} \\
\lambda_3b_{31} &\lambda_3b_{32} &\lambda_3b_{33}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$
 and 
$$BA = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1b_{11}  & \lambda_2b_{12}& \lambda_3b_{13}\\ 
\lambda_1b_{21} &\lambda_2b_{22} &\lambda_3b_{23} \\
\lambda_1b_{31} &\lambda_2b_{32} &\lambda_3b_{33}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Martin Argerami, as you said in $M_3(\mathcal C)$ I have $AB$ and $BA$ as the last comment so I think $B$ must be a diagonal matrix, Am I right?

Comment: Not necessarily. As I mentioned, repeated eigenvalues change things. Do first $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\}=\{1,2,3\}$, then $\{3,3,3\}$, and then $\{2,2,3\}$.